# What does deconstructing a tuple in LINQ Select actually do?

Tags: linq

For a unit test theory using Xunit, I have some data tuples that need to be converted to an `IEnumerable<object[]>`. The data generation method looks like this:

```cs
public static class MathSeeder
{
    public static IEnumerable<(int perfectSquare, int root)> GetIntegerSquareRoots()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            yield return (i * i, i);
        } 
    }
}
```

So I created a property that uses the method defined above as its data for the Xunit theory and attempted to convert the tuple into the required shape.

```cs
public class MathTests
{
    public static IEnumerable<object[]> PerfectSquareRootData { get; set; }
        = MathSeeder.GetIntegerSquareRoots()
            .Select((perfectSquare, squareRoot) => new object[] { perfectSquare, squareRoot})
            .ToList();

    [Theory]
    [MemberData(nameof(PerfectSquareRootData))]
    public void Perfect_squares_have_integer_roots(int perfectSquare, int squareRoot)
    {
        double squareRootDouble = Math.Sqrt(perfectSquare);
        int squareRootInt = (int)squareRoot;
        Assert.Equal(squareRoot, squareRootInt);
    }
}
```

However, the test fails because the LINQ select statement throws an exception. The exception is fixed when I don't deconstruct the tuple and instead call its items one by one.

Even though it's an easy fix, what the hell is the select statement actually doing then?

Comment: afaik Linq (or actually lambda syntax) does not work well with value tuples. The syntax `(perfectSquare, squareRoot) => ` declares an anonymous method with **two `int` parameters**,  not with a single `ValueTuple<int, int>` parameter.

Comment: @RenéVogt I see, any idea what purpose the second `int` parameter represents? From the printed output of the function, it seems to be a simple counter starting from 0 but maybe there's more to it.

Comment: Yes, this Select overload passes the index of the element to the selector.